# ASP.NET 4.5 - unobtrusive validation, model binding, IValidatableObject interface

Tags: data-binding, webforms, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-4.5

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 webforms site, and I'm trying to use all the new fancy features like model binding and unobtrusive validation.

This works quite nicely - as long as I validate only on single fields - e.g. make sure certain values are entered etc.

But when I try to use the `IValidatableObject` interface to establish validations that span multiple fields, I don't get the expected results.

Imagine I have a `MyUser` class generated from a SQL Server database, into an EF 6.1 code-first model. I extend this class by adding a partial class to it which implements the `IValidatableObject` interface:

```
public partial class MyUser : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {
        List<ValidationResult> errors = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if(UserName.Equals(Password, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) 
        {
            errors.Add(new ValidationResult("User name and password cannot be the same"));
        }

        return errors;
    }
}
```

Basically I want to check that user name and password aren't the same - I cannot really do this just on the model class itself, therefore I do it here.

Now in my `Update` (or `Insert`, for that matter) method, I want to check if the data the user has entered on the web form is valid:

```
public void Update(int userId)
{
    MyUser existing = _repo.GetUserById(userId);

    if (existing == null) 
    { 
       // handle error
    }

    TryUpdateModel(existing);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // save
    }
}
```

I would have expected that this `Validate` method on the partial `MyUser` class would be called to check if the model state is valid - but that doesn't seem to happen...

What am I missing? How else would you implement cross-field validations like this?

**Update:** the problems seems to be that the `Validate` method of the `IValidatableObject` interface, implemented in a separate partial class file, isn't properly recognized. Any ideas why??

As soon as I move that method to the main, EF-generated `MyUser.cs` class, then it works just fine. Which is great - until the day I need to re-create my entity classes from the database again, when a database change has been made.....